# Any SMS API is available for android to send SMS from android Application?

Tags: android, api, sms

In my application i want to send a SMS to user ,they are registered to the application without the user interaction. Is it possible in android? yes means how to do that because i don't want to open the default SMS application available in android.

Comment: I need a little clarification, send an SMS to the user or from the user? Or generate a fake SMS on the device as if it were received?

Comment: I want to send a SMS to the user from my application without opening the default SMS application

Comment: Okay but you aren't really sending an SMS to the user if you are already on the device right? So you just want to add a new entry to the SMS storage area on the device -- essentially faking an SMS receipt? I am just trying to understand because it seems like sending an SMS to a device that *you are already on* is a little backwards from a UX perspective. Have you considered just showing a dialog with the message from your application?

Comment: Read this [article](http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android) may it helps you.

Answer (score 9):

Its very simple to send sms using android code-

```
SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
sms.sendTextMessage(NUMBER, null, MESSAGE, null, null);
```

and if you want to capture all the events related to sms like sms sent,delivered then you can refer the link provided in above post by @Ian Newson.
Thanks

Comment: anyway to send message from Website to my Andriod Phone?

Comment: @DeepSan This is get cost from our balance.any option is there to send free sms like this

Answer (score 2):

Check the following link for details on how to send an SMS from an Android app

http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/sms-messaging-android

Answer (score 2):

If you are just trying to send an SMS from the device it almost could not be more simple than using [SmsManager.sendTextMessage](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SmsManager.html#sendTextMessage%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20android.app.PendingIntent,%20android.app.PendingIntent%29)